# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$db_name' (T_VARIABLE)

Tags: php

I feel like I am beating a dead horse. I have tried many of the suggestion here including ; and "" and ; etc. and I keep getting the same error. Could someone give me a hand please? TIA
This is my code:

```
// Connect to the database
$cn = mysqli_connect($db_host, $db_user, $db_pass) or die("Cannot connect to DB");
mysqli_select_db($conn $db_name) or die("Error accessing DB");
```

this is my result:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$db_name' (T_VARIABLE)  in
>   G:\Apache24\htdocs\poster\config.inc.php on line 314

Comment: mysqli_select_db($conn $db_name) - comma missing between $conn and $db_name

Comment: Thank you, but using the comma only gave me more errors...

Answer (score 1):

I think you lack comma:

```
mysqli_select_db($conn,$db_name) or die("Error accessing DB");
```

Comment: Although I'm not sure, I'm not a user of `mysqli`

Comment: I was using "mysql" and the first 'page' of errors I got told me to switch the wording to "mysqli" once I did that I only got the one error which I'm trying to handle now. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

### PHP [mysqli_connect()](https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_mysqli_connect.asp) Function

```
<?php
   $con = mysqli_connect("localhost","my_user","my_password","my_db");

    // Check connection
    if (mysqli_connect_errno())
      {
      echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
      }
    ?>
```